# MethodNotAllowedException in line 207 file upload

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I got MethodNotAllowedException in RouteCollection line 207 exception in my web app.
Next I will copy some of the code that may be interested.

This is the form code in the view.

```
    {!! Form::open(['url' => route('admin.mmk.listings.import'), 'files' => TRUE]) !!}
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
                <b>Atention</b>: for a successfull import, ensure your xml file is valid.<br />
                Please, remove any "&lt;![CDATA[&lt;root&gt;" and "&lt;/root&gt;]]>" tag from your file".<br />
                Check this <a href="{{ asset('resources_template.xml') }}" target="_blank">template</a> if you need help.
            </p>
            <p>
                {!! Form::file('xml', array('accept' => '.xml')) !!}
                <small>Accepted formats: xml</small>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Import</button>
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is the route code:

```
Route::post('listings/import', array(
        'as' => 'admin.mmk.listings.import',
        'uses' => 'MMKController@importListings'
));
```

He just get imported xml file and get his data, store the data in database and save images from external website. It work great for low size xml files but when I import big xml file I got this exception but it still insert data in database.

How can I solve?
Thank you!

Comment: How can I edit?

Comment: Your form using using GET, but the route is POST. Add the method to your form request.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('admin.mmk.listings.import'), 'files' => TRUE, 'method' => 'post']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the route method. Like so:

```
Route::get('listings/import', array(
    'as' => 'admin.mmk.listings.import',
    'uses' => 'MMKController@importListings'));
```

If you still getting this error it means that the problem is not the route method, else change the form method to post in Form::open